# Empty display after refresh on WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control and using NavigateToString to display content. After the call to NavigateToString everything is loaded properly and looks great. However if F5 is pressed the display becomes empty.

How can I allow refresh, but reload the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there is no URL to reload. More precisely, I'd expect the URL to be `about:blank` when using `NavigateToString`. Check `browser.Document.URL` to verify that. You may want to create a temporary file and navigate to it instead.

**[EDITED]** Indeed, `((dynamic)webBrowser.Document).URL` is `about:blank` after `NavigateToString`, so you're reloading a blank page.

Comment: I was hoping I could catch some refresh event and push in my content string again, Oh well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to prevent the refresh, you could just disable F5 key action for `WebBrowser` by handling [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) event.